# How to write nested ternary operator in more optimized way

Tags: javascript, optimization, ternary-operator

I am fetching some big `json` data from back-end and and I have to check the data twice and only then I can use that data. In nested `if` my code is working properly I want to change that in to nested `ternary` condition. following is my code ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueK3A/))

JS:

```
var x = /* Some big JSON data */,fx,yy;
if(x){
    yy = $.parseJSON(decodeURIComponent(x));
    yy ? fx = yy.products.length : fx =0;
}else{
    fx = yy = 0;
}
```

This is what I have tried yet(not working):

```
x ? ($.parseJSON(decodeURIComponent(x)),(yy ? fx = yy.products.length : fx =0;)) : (fx = yy = 0);
```

this is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueK3A/)

Comment: You are trying to replace something that works and you understand with something that is so complicated you can't understand it well enough to write it. May I ask, why do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: With with difficult and complicated situations it's better to use `if else` than `ternary`

Comment: Why do you believe getting everything on one line means it is "optimized"?

Comment: @Jon I think writing it in one line will make it easier and second thing is I believe that ternary executes faster than if and else

Comment: @ChrisHardie I thought ternary operator executes faster than if than else.. and writing the code in one line looks good.. :)

Comment: @BharatSoni: Ternary operator is definitely not faster than if-else. If compiled correctly, both should give the same bytecode. Do not sacrifice readability for premature microoptimisation, especially not if for useless one.

Comment: @Bergi thanks a lot for the advice sir... will take care next time :) is there any books or links for js optimizations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, it would be much better to write this as

```
var x = /* whatever */, fx = 0, yy = 0;

if (x && yy = $.parseJSON(decodeURIComponent(x))) {
    fx = yy.products.length;
}
```

which is immediately clear to the reader.

Another way to write it with idiomatic Javascript (still no ternary operator) would be

```
var x = /* whatever */, yy, fx;
yy = $.parseJSON(decodeURIComponent(x)) || 0;
fx = (yy && yy.products.length) || 0;
```

which you can also write in one line by combining the declarations of `yy` and `fx` with the assignments. That's one statement less than the ternary operator, so if you are "optimizing" for statement count why not do that instead?

Comment: `0 ||` is not idiomatic and could just be omitted. Did you mean `|| 0`?